# combine regex with gitlab variable in rules:if

Tags: regex, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I am trying to combine the regex and $variable in gitlab CI `rules:if` section.
I want to run the stage when the tag is named as : 1.0.1-$MICROSERVICE_IMAGE_NAME while:
`variables: MICROSERVICE_IMAGE_NAME: "app"`

The problem I am facing is that either gitlab complains about the invalid syntax regex or just dont include the Stage in gitlab CI pipeline. I have tried these values for `$CI_COMMIT_TAG` but none of them suppose to work.

```
   - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^\d+\.\d+\.\d+-$MICROSERVICE_IMAGE_NAME/
   - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ ^\d+\.\d+\.\d+-$MICROSERVICE_IMAGE_NAME
   - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^\d+\.\d+\.\d+-'"$MICROSERVICE_IMAGE_NAME'"/
```

However if I only use the value of $variable as CI_COMMIT_TAG name and create a tag with this variable value, it works fine e.g.

```
- if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ $MICROSERVICE_IMAGE_NAME
```

so the only problem is when I want to combine both, the regex and the $variable `$MICROSERVICE_IMAGE_NAME`
can anyone tell me where I am making mistake?

Comment: As I understand it, you can't interpolate variables into a regex rule. However, you can interpolate variables into other variables... Maybe you can make a variable with the desired pattern like `TAG_PATTERN: '/^\d+\.\d+\.\d+-$MICROSERVICE_IMAGE_NAME/'` then `- if: ... =~ $TAG_PATTERN` ? Not sure if that works.